# Error: exception in thread 'main' java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error, program-entry-point

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestMultiDimenArray
{
    private static int row;
    private static int column;
    public static int [][] table1 = new int [row][column];

    public static int [][] get ( int a, int b){
        row = a;
        column = b;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int n = 0; n < a; n++){
            for (int m = 0; m < b; m++){
                table1[n][m] = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return table1;
    }

    public static void display (int [][] array1){
        for (int n = 0; n < row; n++){
            for (int m = 0; m < column; m++){
                System.out.print(table1[n][m] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
            get(3,3);
    }
}
```

The program is compiled successfully but when I run it, it return the error. How can I fix it? That is all I can tell about my problem. What is wrong with the system that tells me to give more detail when that is all I can tell.

Comment: Did you try to debug your program? What do you think you are doing with `public static int [][] table1 = new int [row][column];`? What are the values of `row` and `column` when this statement is reached? Java is not Excel...

Answer (score 3):

This statement declares a 2D array of length 0 and width 0.

```
public static int [][] table1 = new int [row][column];
```

This is because `row` and `column` haven't been assigned anything when the class is initialized; they are assigned only when `get` is called.  So Java assigns them the default value of `0`.

Initialize the array after you assign `row` and `column` values from the parameters.

```
public static int [][] table1;

public static int [][] get ( int a, int b){
    row = a;
    column = b;
    table1 = new int [row][column];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Rest unchanged
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set dynamicaly the size of your table1  array.
Make sure a and b are lower or equal to raw and column.

(If you re-create your table1, I don't think you'll be able to get any data into it)